# Generate an OCX activex control using Visual C#

Tags: .net, dll, activex, ocx

I am working on a project to generate OCX control but I found that the project type in Visual c# is class library and the file it generates is a DLL .

I want to know how to generate the OCX control in Visual C#, since I haven't found any place to set this in the project properties in Visual C# .

The question is how to convert DLL to OCX. Is it possible using C#?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2fe50909-f7f8-4500-a99c-34de2ef567f6/activex-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral